# how to take accelerometer output and plot on s xy graphg

Tags: ios, xcode

I just want to do a simple xy plot of someone standing up from a chair.
Can anyone recommend code snippet or other example of this application?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Apple's example of that very thing.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html)